# How can I specify the target platform when using libclang to analyse C code?

Tags: gcc, libclang

I am using a source code analysis tool using Clang (version 6.0.1).  The source code I want to analyse was written for an ARM processor and will be compiled using arm-none-eabi-gcc. My tool is running on Linux or Windows.  How can I tell libclang to analyze this code for the target platform,  not the host platform?

When calling clang_indexSourceFile(...) to analyze the source code,  I give it the same -D and -I options that I use for arm-none-eabi-gcc,  including options that are implicitly added by arm-none-eabi-gcc.  These can be obtained by running the following command:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -v -dM -E - </dev/null
```

I am also passing these ARM_specific flags to both arm-none-eabi-gcc and clang_indexSourceFile(...): -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard

Still,  libclang uses built-in type sizes matching the host platform (Linux or Windows) instead of the target platform (Arm).  One way to test this it the following, admittedly somewhat contrived code:

```
int c = 1;
switch (c) {
    case sizeof(long double): return 1;
    case 16: return 2;
    default: return 0;
}
```

When I analyze this code with libclang,  I get a diagnostic "Duplicate case value '16'" proving that it assumes that a long double is 16 bytes.  With arm-none-eabi-gcc, I do not get this error (but I get a similar error when I replace 16 by 8).

Answer (score -1):

Use -target arm-none-eabi as an option in he clang_indexSourceFile(...) call.  Thank you Ivan Kosarev for suggesting this solution.